# Problem creating lxc container on BQ M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lxc, container, libertine

I attempted to create an lxc container on my BQ Aquarius M10 as follows:

```
libertine-container-manager create -t lxc -d vivid -i lxc
```

After being asked for and entering my password the following was the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/libertine-container-manager", line 758, in <module>
args.func(args)
File "/usr/bin/libertine-container-manager", line 387, in create
container = LibertineContainer(args.id)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libertine/Libertine.py", line 281, in __init__
from  libertine.LxcContainer import LibertineLXC
ImportError: No module named 'libertine.LxcContainer'
```

Can anyone explain this?

Just to note - I am running OTA-11 and ssh'd into my tablet to get around any restricted terminal issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usermode LXC is not supported on Linux 3.10, so the LXC back end of Libertine isn't even installed on that device.  If you try to force the tools to perform such an unsupported option, you get an error message telling you that the back end is not available.

The solution to this problem is don't force the tools to use an unsupported option.

Comment: Thanks for that.   
I can see now that 'https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Libertine' does say that most ubuntu-touch hardware doesn't support LXC containers.  
I haven't been able to find much documentation on how containers are supposed to work, or what the planned development for them is. Coud you point me to anything?

Comment: @Stephen M. Webb Thank you for the answer. Do you know by any chance about the current situation re lxc/lxd support on ubuntu-touch? I was trying to set-up a web-server on my old Nexus 4, but couldn't manage to run lxc (my project is lxc-based). I've asked the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143091/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-for-lxc-on-a-smartphone-arm-or-x86/1143666#1143666), but it currently leads me away from ubuntu-touch in the other [direction](https://superuser.com/questions/1439383/how-to-use-android-sdk-and-smartphone-vendor-tools-to-boot-another-kernel). Thank you.

Comment: I am also relying on the old post by [Stéphane Graber](https://stgraber.org/category/ubuntu-touch/) - section "LXC on Android devices". According to him LXC support on Android devices hasn't been a priority, although it was generally possible...