# Ubuntu Touch (UBports) and Android support for LXC/LXD containers (for running Ubuntu): current state

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, lxc

I am trying to run a web-server on my Android device (several available models, ARM or x86 hardware) inside a container (lxc / lxd). Looking for the easiest and safest way to do it. I was thinking about [installing ubuntu-server on a smartphone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143091/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-for-lxc-on-a-smartphone-arm-or-x86/1143666#1143666). The task has led me in the direction of unlocking the [bootloader](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Bootloader), replacing the [recovery](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Recovery) and flashing a custom ROM (which needs to be found / chosen / tested / trusted OR developed). Before diving into [xda-developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=XDA-Developers:Android&ajax=0) forum and Android SDK docs I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to make lxc / lxd run directly on Android (which version).

The only (very old) post by [Stéphane Graber](https://stgraber.org/author/stgraber/) on the subject - [section "LXC on Android devices"](https://stgraber.org/category/ubuntu-touch/) - has left me rather pessimistic. According to him LXC support on Android devices hasn't been a priority, although it was generally possible...

I've also come across mentioning of [lxc-android-config](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Testing/lxc-android-config) tool: [here](https://github.com/ubports/lxc-android-config) and [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc-android-config/0.230+16.04.20160328-0ubuntu1). However it lacks documentation or any kind of user-oriented notes.

Related questions:

1)[How to install ubuntu server for lxc on a smartphone (ARM or x86)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143091/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-for-lxc-on-a-smartphone-arm-or-x86/1143666#1143666)

2)[How to use Android SDK and smartphone vendor tools to boot another kernel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1439383/how-to-use-android-sdk-and-smartphone-vendor-tools-to-boot-another-kernel)

Comment: You should ask UBports team on their forum https://forums.ubports.com/ . Ubuntu touch is not supported here.

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you, I will. I still would like to ask here since it is a major and well-structured Q&A site for linux / debian / ubuntu distro branch. I believe the subject relates to Ubuntu (since it is about running ubuntu in containers on other platforms)... I've just corrected the question topic to make it clear.

Comment: Ubuntu Touch questions should be on topic here. However, repeatedly asking the same very broad questions over and over and over across multiple SE sites, is not cool.